Why are some read-only processor registers inaccessible in EL0?
What is the security provided by making read-only system registers like Processor Feature Register 1 or Instruction Set Attribute Register 1 inaccessible to code running at EL0?
If code is running at EL0, how can it know which instructions are legal without the ability to query these kinds of things?

@artlessnoise EL0 is the least privileged exception level.

@Siguza Rings a bell.  I didn't think someone would ask a question if it was the least privileged.  Thanks for the clarification.


If code is running at EL0, how can it know which instructions are legal without the ability to query these kinds of things?

The operating system (which runs at EL1 or higher) is supposed to define some mechanism to inform EL0 code of the CPU capabilities.  For instance, Linux exposes these bits via hwcap flags.
This way, the OS has complete control over what the unprivileged code knows about the hardware.
I agree that for some of these flags, there doesn't seem to be any particular danger in letting EL0 know their values.  But some of them, EL0 also has no need to know (e.g. for features that aren't available at EL0 anyway).  And there could be cases where you really want to sandbox your EL0 code, and don't want to leak any information about the hardware.
Also note that some CPU features, even if present in hardware, can be disabled at EL0, e.g. if the necessary software support isn't present in the kernel.  (For instance, SVE can only be safely used if the OS has code to save and restore the SVE registers on context switch.)  So allowing EL0 to directly inquire about hardware support isn't really useful, since it has to ask the OS anyway if that support is actually enabled.
Again, some of the flags still seem harmless.  But ARM probably found it simpler and safer just to adopt a blanket policy of "not available to EL0, let the OS decide".

Consider also: trapping and emulating instructions that the underlying hardware doesn't natively support.

That all makes sense.  I'm writing bare-metal code, so I will have to add that layer so portions that run in EL0 can always do the right thing.

The standard in emulation is that I should be able to run a program in EL0, but the program thinks it's running on bare metal.  The gold standard is that bare metal is sometimes different than the actual hardware the machine is running on.
So any instruction that lets the program know that it's being lied to has to be a privileged instruction, so that the emulator can continue the fiction. Sometimes the OS has to tell a program what it wants to hear rather than the truth.
